# fiona ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'str'

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, fiona

Why below code does not work-

```
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

my_schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'mean_in': 'str', 'total_h1': 'str', 'total_h2': 'str', 'LOS': 'str', 'id': 'str', 'index': 'str', 'Junctio': 'str', 'intLanes': ':str', 'flow': 'str', 'incLanes': 'str', 'interva1': 'str', 'y': 'str', 'x': 'str', 'entered': 'str', 'type': 'str', 'Incomin': 'str', 'interva2': 'str'}}
wr_dict = {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'mean_in': '0', 'index': '0', 'Junctio': '0', 'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'flow': '0', 'total_h1': '0', 'total_h2': '0', 'LOS': '0', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'interva1': '0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'entered': '0', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A', 'Incomin': '0', 'interva2': '0'}}

with fiona.open("my_shp_clean1.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
    output.write(wr_dict)
```

Rather raises exception as below-

> File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\fiona__init__.py",
>   line 183, in open   enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, crs_wkt=crs_wkt)
>   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py",
>   line 161, in **init**   self.session.start(self, **kwargs) File
>   "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\fiona\ogrext.pyd", line 890,
>   in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start (fiona/ogrext.c:15383)
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'str'

N.B. I am with Fiona (1.6.2),Shapely (1.5.13),GDAL (1.11.3) and python 2.7 in windows 8

Answer (score 2):

I guess its because you have a typo in your schema properties :
 **`'intLanes': ':str'`** should be changed to **`'intLanes': 'str'`** (the  colon before `str`).

Comment: Thanks, What about the second part of the question, why ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'str' is raised?

Comment: You might find that fiona (and underneath ogr) default to an int datatype when they don't understand the schema. You'd have to check the source to be sure though.

Comment: Because, with your schema, Fiona don't know what is the `':str'`format and, by defaut, it choose the first format that is `int`